# i getting stack overflow error in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

i am a beginner in flash but not in object oriented progarming. 
iam making a business simulation multiplayer board game.this salute function is called from an .fla file and this **salute** function calls moveto function.the **salute** function working fine.but the problem comes at **moveto()** at **dialog2.x=200;**.if i remove that line the problem goes to next line please help me

```
 public function salute(a:Array)
{
    a[0].x=200;
    a[0].y=200;
    if(k==0)
    {
    tilehold.amount.text=String(amount);
    tilehold.networth.text=String(networth);
    tilehold.playertitle.text=playername;
    dialog2=a[1];
    dialog3=a[2];
    dialog4=a[3];
    dialog5=a[4];
    dialog6=a[5];
    forbuild=a[6];
    k=1
    }
    a[0].dialogtext.text=playername+"'s turn";
    a[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,nothing1);
    function nothing1(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        a[0].x=1000;
        e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,nothing1);
        a[7].x=-10;
        a[7].y=-10;
        a[7].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wheelspin);
    }
    function wheelspin(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        spinvalue=Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
        a[7].wheel.spin(spinvalue);
        a[7].wheel.gotoAndPlay(2);
        e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wheelspin);
        a[7].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wheelmove);
    }
    function wheelmove(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        a[7].x=1000;
        e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wheelmove);

    }
    moveto();
}
public function moveto()
{
    if(spinvalue==0||spinvalue==7||spinvalue==8||spinvalue==9)
    {
        if(nooflandsown==0)
        {
```

> /* the above one is working fine but,this error indicating below line*/

```
                            dialog2.x=200;
            dialog2.dialogtext.text="you dont own any land";
            dialog2.okbut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nothing2);
            function nothing2(e:MouseEvent)
            {
                dialog2.x=1000;
                e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nothing2);
                endturn();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            dialog3.x=200;
            dialog3.y=200;
            dialog3.dialogtext.text="do you want to build";
            dialog3.yesbut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wanttobuild);
            dialog3.nobut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nothing3);
            function wanttobuild(e:MouseEvent)
            {
            dialog3.x=1000;
            e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wanttobuild);
            dialog3.nobut.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nothing3);
             chooseland();
            }
            function nothing3(e:MouseEvent)
            {
                dialog3.x=1000;
                dialog3.yesbut.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wanttobuild);
            e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,nothing3);
            endturn();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        l=(currentposition+spinvalue)%18;
        this.pos=l;
        switch(currentposition)
        {
            case 1:
            this.gotoAndPlay(15);
            break;
            case 2:
            this.gotoAndPlay(25);
            break;
            case 3:
            this.gotoAndPlay(35);
            break;
            case 4:
            this.gotoAndPlay(55);
            break;
            case 5:
            this.gotoAndPlay(65);
            break;
            case 6:
            this.gotoAndPlay(75);
            break;
            case 7:
            this.gotoAndPlay(85);
            break;
            case 8:
            this.gotoAndPlay(105);
            break;
            case 9:
            this.gotoAndPlay(115);
            break;
            case 10:
            this.gotoAndPlay(125);
            break;
            case 11:
            this.gotoAndPlay(135);
            break;
            case 12:
            this.gotoAndPlay(145);
            break;
            case 13:
            this.gotoAndPlay(165);
            break;
            case 14:
            this.gotoAndPlay(175);
            break;
            case 15:
            this.gotoAndPlay(195);
            break;
            case 16:
            this.gotoAndPlay(205);
            break;
            case 17:
            this.gotoAndPlay(215);
            break;
            default:
            this.gotoAndPlay(1);
        }
        currentposition=l;


    }
}
```

please help me out. i tried a lot by changing the entire code.but i cant figure that out

Comment: Not sure why this is getting so many down votes without an explanation. Anyway could you post the stack overflow error you are getting. If `dialog2.x = 200;` is causing the stack overflow error, I can only assume you have overridden the display object's `x`setter method. Probably looks something like `override public function set x(value:Number) { this.x = value; }`, this is just a guess.

Comment: check this:  in wheelspin you say a[7].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wheelmove);  then in wheel move you again say e.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,wheelmove); which is a[7] yet again.

Answer (score 0):

First, why adding event listener inside an event listener (function `wheelmove`)? And second, check if you actually exit `moveto()` function WITHOUT another call of `salute()`, if no, then you have to alter your code flow logic elsewhere. Also, in case of large code, you may use PasteBin service in the Internet to host the code.

Comment: sorry that is a removeEventlistener (wheelmove) and what do you mean by exiting moveto() this move to further calls another function

Comment: Yes, moveto() is calling endturn(), which in turn calls salute()? You have effectively created an infinite recursion scenario. You have to redo your logic so that your function will eventually end executing, and next phase of execution should start from event listeners. This is what's called architecture, to make your code into smaller blocks and design a way for them to move as a single entity.

Comment: Error: Error #1023: Stack overflow occurred.
 at game_fla::MainTimeline/frame5()[game_fla.MainTimeline::frame5:75]
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property cost not found on Land1 and there is no default value.
 at Icon4/buyorrent()[D:\game\Icon4.as:318]
 at Icon4/frame35()[Icon4::frame35:5]

Comment: a is an array of movieclips in which a[7] is wheel i used in the game

Comment: Please provide source code of functions: `endturn()`, `chooseland()`, for example, by updating the question, and check again if something calls `moveto()` when it's actually called from `moveto()`, even if indirectly.

Comment: i was making a multi player game . in which a loop continues untill only one player remained.is this continues loop causes stackoverflow but i used **break;** statement to end the loop

Comment: You should use enter frame loop instead of this, as this nests itself, while enterframe loop is purely iterative and does not cause stack overflow.

Comment: but i used MovieClip(root).gotoAndplay(6); at the end of turn, where root consists of two frames 5, 6; in each frame a player's  turn s executed i used MovieClip(root).gotoAndplay(6) at first player end of turn and MovieClip(root).gotoAndplay(5); at second player end turn

Comment: I've said, check if your `moveto` function is called from somewhere that is in turn called from `moveto()`. If so, eliminate endless recursion at all costs. I can't say more without any sources.

Comment: the travesal is **player1.salute() -> moveto() -> buyorrent() -> endturn()**;will the control returns to the next statement to **salute()** if i dont write any thing in **endturn()**;because the next statement will be **player2.salute()**     i have checked there is no such recursion as moveto calling moveto

Comment: It will return only if all of the functions will perform a return. So, when it reaches `endturn()`, you should make it so that all of `endturn`, `buyorrent` and `moveto` functions to perform a return, and only then the statement in `player1.salute()` after calling `moveto()` will execute.

Comment: i resolved the stackoverflow problem by calling the main timeline frame belongs to second player from endturn function func of first and from endturn function of first to a frame which calls the frame which belongs to player1 it worked fine.but now iam getting the 
**ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable MainTimeline is not defined.** what should i do now sir

Comment: I think start another question and provide relevant code there. Perhaps you have indeed solved the endless recursion, and now need help elsewhere.